# Linkage between Task created from sharepoint workflow

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have a Sharepoint 2013 List called L1 (Vacation Request).

I created a SharePoint Designer 2013 Workflow on change of L1 and the workflow creates a Task and assigns it to a user (Approver)

Now on Approval or Rejection of the Task, I need to update the Status (Approved/Rejected) in L1.

How can I achieve this?

How do I find the linkage between Task and List item?

Comment: What Sharepoint version are you working in? And if in 2013 or SPO, what version type of workflow is it?

Comment: SharePoint 2013 Workflow

Answer (score 0):

When your workflow starts it run in context of the list/library item. It's available to you as "Current item". So when the task status will be updated you can update item in L1 list with "Current Item" variable. 
You can use "Update list item" action, then by default first on the list is "Current item" and then when you press "Add" button you will see all columns related to your L1 list.